# Swift: Expected declaration of var even though it has been declared

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and trying to program a simple counter app. I'd like to post messages on the screen depending on the value of a variable. But I can't access it even though (I think) it's not an instance variable.
What did I do wrong?

```
var rowValue: Int = 0    
@IBOutlet weak var motivationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rowCount: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func subtractRowButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if rowValue > 0 {
        rowValue = rowValue - 1
    } else {
        rowValue = 0
    }

    rowCount.text = "\(rowValue)"

}

@IBAction func addRowButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    rowValue = rowValue + 1
    rowCount.text = "\(rowValue)"

    if rowValue < 10 {
        println("Not bad")
    } else if rowValue > 9 && rowValue < 20 {
        println("Awesome")
    }
}   

@IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    rowValue = 0
    rowCount.text = "\(rowValue)"
}
```

Comment: Please, fix the code formatting. 
And specify, where exactly does problem come? In what row do you face the problem?

Comment: In your code at bottom side you written `if` condition  is outside of any function in class which is not possible, fix it.

Comment: I can't access "rowValue" in the finale if statement. Besides I get errors stating that consecutive statements need to be separated by ";", even though it makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: Your Syntax is also wrong in `if` part as well as `else` part, first decide in which function you want to add this code, you can not write conditional statement in class. Conditional statement must be enclosed in function.

Comment: okay. Put the if statement inside the IBActions. Now I get "Expected "{" after "if" condition"

Comment: Check edited question and replace it with your code, this will removes your most of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is not for any `var`. Its because of you have written that code directly inside `class` not inside any `function`. That is causing the issue.

Replace your `conditional block` with something like

```
 func doSomething(){
   if(rowValue < 10)
   {
    println("Not bad")
   }
   else if(rowValue > 9 && rowValue < 20)
   {
    println("Awesome")
   }
 }
```

And call this function `doSomething()` wherever you want.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!